# Eclipse: Maven plugin disappears after installing Spring IDE

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I'm using Eclipse Mars for Java EE developers so it already comes with Maven plugin installed. However, after installing the Spring IDE from marketplace and restarting eclipse I get the following error:

```
No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.m2e.editor.MavenPomEditor
```

Maven completely disappears. Can't find it by right clicking on project or in the project properties. So I can't even create a new Maven project.

Also the Maven Libraries folder from previous project becomes renamed to "Persisted container" and the jar files in there can no longer be referenced.

Comment: @PratikAmbani thank you. I have installed and started using STS now and having no issues with it.

Comment: @PratikAmbani I mean it works as an alternative answer to the question so I guess you could

Comment: @PratikAmbani Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to upvote it. But I have marked it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the errors while setting up Project Environments are due to improper project setup in our IDEs. Spring community has customized eclipse for all Spring related projects, called Spring STS. You can download it from [here](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all). It comes with preloaded plugins required for Spring projects. I would recommend you to use it as you are habitual with eclipse.

Alternatively I would suggest you to use IntelliJ(my favourite) from IDEA. You can download it from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Answer (score 0):

This is known or open issue with Spring IDE. [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/133)

To fix you need to install Core/Spring IDE from the manual install site. Here are the URL: http://springide.org/updatesite

These are the steps you need to follow: 
Go to Eclipse IDE, click “Help” -> “Install New Software…”. Type “http://springide.org/updatesite” to access the Spring IDE update site.

Restart Eclipse after finished.

Thanks,